# How to trigger an alert in AWS based on values in a table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alert, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-dynamodb-streams

i monitor data quality of ingested data in AWS. Example:

| ID | customer | Sales | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | henry | 5000 | 4000 |
| 2 | melissa | 10000 | abc |

One dataset might have 20 validation checks. Each validation check creates an entry in a result table.

| validation run | validation name | checked column | unexpected values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-04 | are values numeric | Sales | 0 |
| 2021-11-04 | are values numeric | Cost | 1 |

Now i want to create an alert when one of these entries are >0 (like in column "unexpected values").

Target should be that the alert goes to the SNS Topic. I know Cloudwatch or DynamoDB can monitor tables, but more on the infrastructure site (is data ingested,...). Do you know how i can monitor and create an event if certain values are present in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you know how i can monitor and create an event if certain values are present in the table?

You stream to **lambda function**, and function monitors the values. If the lambda detects the values of interests, its going to perform further actions, e.g. send SNS notification or trigger some automations.

If you really want CloudWatch Alarms, then the lambda function would populate **custom CloudWatch Metrics**, for which you would setup your alarms.